# Is there a need to set max_length in a model field?

Tags: python, django, database, database-design, django-models

I'm working on a Django app, and I was wondering if there is any reason to explicitly set a `max_length` for a model field (TextField specifically, but I'm interested for all fields).

Does it reduce the table size, or improve efficiency? Does a smaller max_length have advantages over a larger one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it in CharField since it defaults to None, I believe.  But there are some cases, like phone number, or ssn, or US State abbreviations  where it will guide the user to type in a certain correct length of characters.  According to the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField

class TextField([**options])
A large text field. The default form widget for this field is a Textarea.

Changed in Django 1.7:
If you specify a max_length attribute, it will be reflected in the Textarea widget of the auto-generated form field. However it is not enforced at the model or database level. Use a CharField for that.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand correctly, other than validation it doesn't matter? And would picking a smaller max_lenth for CharField offer any advantages over picking a larger one?

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on how the db declares space for varchar.  I'm not sure that would matter in many cases.

Comment: @Parker, it matters if you exceed certain limits. In MySQL, old versions had a limit on VARCHAR of 255, while newer versions have a limit of 65,535. Also, rows are subject to total size of 65,535 bytes, which the content in a VARCHAR is subject to but the content of a TEXT is not. Check your database's specs.